# Create new Instance of function referenced by a variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object, instance

I'm trying to create a way to store and load maps for an HTML5 canvas game. In order to do so, I must create new instances of objects (functions) referenced by a variable. This is my code.

```
    function Map(w, h) {
        if (typeof w == "undefined")
            this.width = 640;
        else
            this.width = w;

        if (typeof h == "undefined")
            this.height = 480;
        else
            this.height = h;

        this.obj = new Array();
        this.x = new Array();
        this.y = new Array();
        this.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0";
    }

    Map.prototype.addObject = function(cl, xx, yy) {
        this.obj.push(cl);
        this.x.push(xx);
        this.y.push(yy);
    }

    function newInstance(o, x, y) {
        this.tmp = new o(); //This is what doesn't work.
        tmp.x = x;
        tmp.y = y;
        objects.push(tmp);
        tmp.create();
    }

    Map.prototype.load = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.obj.length; i++) {
            newInstance(this.obj[i], this.x[i], this.y[i]);
        }
    }
```

I want it to be used as such:

```
    //When I create the map.
    var mMain = new Map();

    //This cannot be new Player() and new Block() because I don't want to load the map yet. I'm just creating the map.
    mMain.addObject(Player, 320, 240);
    mMain.addObject(Block, 0, 256);
    mMain.addObject(Block, 32, 256);
    //etc...

    //When I load the map.
    mMain.load();
```

Just an example of how the Player and Block objects work.

```
    function Player() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        //Other variables irrelevant to this problem.
    }
    //Block object code
```

Comment: Why can't it be: `mMain.addObject(new Player, 320, 240)` ?

Comment: Because that would be creating the object when the map was being created, not when it was being loaded. All of the maps are created at the beginning of the game, but they are only loaded once the player enters that map.

Comment: change Player to `new Player()` and Block to `new Block()`
Also, instead of using `new Array()` you should just declare arrays like this `[]`

Comment: yeah sorry saw it after I posted

Comment: Your `//doesn't work` code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/xzxKp/

Comment: That's really weird. The jsfiddle one works, but when I open the HTML file for my game in Google Chrome, I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I had forgotten to check all of my code before posting, so I gave false information. Instead of "function Player()", I had "var Player = ObjectResource;" because I wanted it to extend the ObjectResource function. I just had to change it to what I had posted.